# Release bitmaps on pagetransform() method in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-glide

I have three fragment in viewpager each of which comprises of recyclerview showing images. As the images are large and also some of them are GIF, I am getting OOM errors in low devices. I also tried setting viewpageroffscreenlimit to one, but then page swiping lags because adapter is set again. Delaying setting adapter on pageselected gives bad user experience.

I am using glide in loading images. I just want that my content remains as it is, but image releases on page change and when user comes back to that page only images are loaded again. I read about Glide.clear but don't know where to implement it. Actually I want to retain all three fragments but simultaneously release all images when page is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can change bitmap format: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Configuration#bitmap-format

Also if I remember correctly Glide always tries to load best fitting image into ImageView. If your view is defined as wrap_content it loads as big image as possible, in such case you might define ImageView dimensions with precise dp or match_parent.

If you would share some XML and ViewHolders code I would be able to better pin point places for optimisation.